# Using Python how do I generate a random number within a range for each row in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, random

**Objective:** to create a unique and random number for each row within the constructed field 'Birth'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6])])
df1['Birth']= random.randrange(1905,1995, len(df1))
df1
```

The above code produces a single random number for all rows as follows:

```
    A   B   Birth
0   1   4   1974
1   2   5   1974
2   3   6   1974
```

I am instead interested in the following:

```
    A   B   Birth
0   1   4   1904
1   2   5   1978
2   3   6   1934
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using numpy

```
import numpy as np
df['Birth'] = np.random.randint(1905,1995, len(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6])])
```

Try:

```
df1['Birth'] = df1.apply(lambda x: random.randrange(1905,1995, len(df1)),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  Birth
0  1  4   1980
1  2  5   1947
2  3  6   1965
```

What you are doing is the same as creating a static variable and using it for all of the values in the df like this:

```
a_variable = random.randrange(1905,1995, len(df1))
#a_variable = 1974
df1['Birth'] = a_variable
```